# Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address

Tags: http, webserver, apache

Previously my IP was 10.0.6.63 , the apache server was working fine.

On reboot DHCP changed my IP address to 10.0.15.12 Now when i try to start apache it is giving me following error

```
$service httpd restart
```

Starting httpd: [Fri Jan 11 16:17:28 2013] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.0.6.63:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Sorry guys, mistake. I had another configuration in /etc which was overriding the local configuration . which was configured for old ip.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a moving IP address do no use **IP based virtualhosts** but **named based virtulahosts**.

Check this [apache documentation link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: I am not using IP bases Virualhosts

Comment: So where does that IP comes from? maybe you use it instead of a DNS' or it is a fixed DNS on your host file?  If you use named based VH simply ensure you use a name which always return the right IP.

Comment: I am using dhcp. ServerName 10.0.15.12:825 Listen 825 and have ssl configuration. I am not getting why its using old ip and port 80? Is this related to router or somthing. In conf files I haven't mention port 80 anywhere or old ip.

Comment: start an httpd -S or apache2 -S to lists the Virtualhosts confogurations, you may have an * or *:80 which means "all available ips of that machine"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check httpd.conf(default config file name) config file.

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
```

you can change you server ip address .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I resolved it by disabling or commenting out 
this line `Listen 192.168.1.80:80` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

I am running Virtualmin on a Centos 5.11

Comment: better replace with your new ip ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file:

```
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so 
#Listen 443
```

Comment out these lines

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem with apache but when i checked , I got that, the particular IP address on which my server is trying to bind is not there as that interface was deleted when my machine was rebooted.
I did following :

1. run `dhclient` to get the interface and IP
2. given command to create the sub interface which I had created for my apache server to listen :  `ifconfig ens6:1 10.10.0.80/16 up`